# Proper URL format of youtube mix for grabbing particular URL of videos

Tags: youtube

I've seen two types of URL on youtube playlists. First one is this:
`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCB9F975ECF01953C`

When you click on "Play all" button then the URL playlist change to this:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otm9NaT9OWU&list=PLCB9F975ECF01953C`

Most URL grabbers works with first type of URL. For example I can use [this one](https://github.com/pierlauro/playlist2links) following way:

```
./playlist2links.sh PLCB9F975ECF01953C
```

Now I have playlist (in fact it is a youtube mix not playlist) which URL looks like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiInBOVHpO8&list=RDQ23sJ-emqds&index=27
```

How can I convert this URL to proper format? I've tried following but both gives errors:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDQ23sJ-emqds&index=27
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDQ23sJ-emqds
```

EDIT:
I've tried also following:

```
┌─[wakatana@~/yt] [12 files, 60Kb]
└──> youtube-dl --version
2015.11.01

┌─[wakatana@~/yt] [12 files, 60Kb]
└──> youtube-dl -v -s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiInBOVHpO8&list=RDQ23sJ-emqds&index=27
[1] 5872
[2] 5873
[2]+  Done                    list=RDQ23sJ-emqds

┌─[wakatana@~/yt] [12 files, 60Kb]
└──> [debug] System config: []
[debug] User config: []
[debug] Command-line args: [u'-v', u'-s', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiInBOVHpO8']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs UTF-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8
[debug] youtube-dl version 2015.07.28
[debug] Python version 2.7.10 - Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
[debug] exe versions: avconv 11.4-6, avprobe 11.4-6, ffmpeg 0.8.17-6
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[youtube] UiInBOVHpO8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] UiInBOVHpO8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] UiInBOVHpO8: Extracting video information
[youtube] UiInBOVHpO8: Downloading DASH manifest
[youtube] UiInBOVHpO8: Downloading DASH manifest

[1]+  Done                    youtube-dl -v -s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiInBOVHpO8
```

The one option that is partially working is to display source code of given page and simply search for lines containing `data-video-title` pattern. There is also video `data-video-id` on same line which allows to reconstruct given video URL. Problem is that the youtube-mix is dynamically generated and this does not works for latest few videos in the play-list (those that are gray), another problem is that this does not works e.g. with `wget` do not know why.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiInBOVHpO8&list=RDQ23sJ-emqds&index=27
is a "youtube-mix", not a list manually created by someone.

[Youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) does a proper job of detecting the list URL, you might want to have a look at its code to see how it detects the playlist URL.

Note it has an option --get-id to directly return the video ids, it might solve your problem as a replacement to playlist2links.sh.